# How to uninstall Unlocked Package that contains Experience Bundle

Tags: community, unlocked-package, 2gp, experience-bundle

How to uninstall the unlocked package that contains Experience Bundle?

Attempt to uninstall fails with the next error

```
*Digital experience name* could not be removed during uninstall.
```

I tried to release a new package version without an experience bundle, upgrade on target org, and again try to delete, but still have this error.
Is it possible or this package would stay on target org forever?

Answer (score 0):

Remove manually reference from Unlocked package to the Digital Experience site.

Also it is a good idea to archive the Digital Experience Site since you can't actually remove it.

After references from Unlocked package to Digital Experience site are removed by the UI, unlocked package can be successfully uninstalled.

Comment: ```Remove manually reference from Unlocked package to the Digital Experience site.```
Digital Experience site is not listed as an item in ```Metadata Components Included in Package```

Comment: it was listed for me

Comment: let me check later what was exactly the metadata type

Comment: Looks like when you remove it from unlocked package and create a new package version, it doesn't work, but I think it worked for me when I had inside the package but removed manually from UI

Comment: Do you see the Digital Experience site listed as "Metadata components included in the package" list on org where such package installed?

Comment: I have seen on one org where I was able to uninstall successfully, but I can't see on the org where I am not able to uninstall